# spring rest many to many response

Tags: java, spring, rest, jackson

I have three classes.
User can organize one event or be attendee for many events.
Event can have only one organizer and have lot of attendees.
Attende - table binding user with event, and have additional fields (Thats why i do not use @ManyToMany annotation)

I want my response show user with events he attend, but somehow exclude "user" field in Attendee class.
And when I looking for events, i want exclude "event" in Attendee class.

I thougt about create Dto for User representation and Event representation, but i feel like it will duplicate all my code.
Is it any way to annotate Attendee class, so for Event it will display one thing, and for User it will diplay another thing?
I read about @JsonManagedReference and @JsonBackReference, but not shure it will help me here.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "calendar_users")
public class User extends BaseEntity {

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
    private List<Attendee> attendeeEvents;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "organizer")
    private List<Event> organizedEvents;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "events")
public class Event extends BaseEntity {

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User organizer;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "event")
    private List<Attendee> attendees;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "attendees")
public class Attendee extends BaseEntity {

    private Date responseTime;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "response_status_id")
    private ResponseStatus responseStatus;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "event_id")
    private Event event;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually correct solution is to add DTO objects to deliver only necessary info.

But for the simple case you can define two classes Attendee and AttendeeSimple (without events). And use the 2 different entities for in User and Event.

Could be simpler if Attendee extends AttendeeSimple.